# jQuery run function onchange as on/off state and not repeat itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple checkboxes running `onchange="calculatetotal()"`. Then I have a function for each of these checkboxes that adds/removes a row to the first empty row in the table. The problem is that since everytime a checkbox is clicked the `total` is calculated, when a row has been added by another checkbox, its added for a second time. How can I make each checkbox add its row only once and at the same time keep updating the total?

```
    calculatetotal = function () {
        var total = applecalc() + orangecalc() + pearcalc();
        alert(total);  
    }

    function applecalc() {
      var price = 0;
      var btn = $('#chkbx');
      var firstemptyrow = $('#tableid tr:empty:eq(0)');
      var removepreviousrow = $('.xxx');

      if (btn.is(':checked')) {
        price = 3;
        firstemptyrow.append('<td class="xxx">apple</td><td class="xxx">$3</td>');
      } else {
        price = 0;            
        removepreviousrow.remove();
      }
      return price;
    }
```

Comment: In the meantime I have separated the part of the function calculating the price from the part that edits the table, the first one is triggered by calculatetotal() and the second one by .click(function(). Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: en the calculatetotal function you can use the event to get the DOM object that was changed, and from there get the <tr> you want to deal with, and only add that. But IMHO this won't work if you have the following scenario: 1. change row #1, 2. change row #2, 3. change row #1 again. You will still keep adding row#1 multiple times. Maybe you'll need to calculate the real total each time...